# How to implement openvpn in bitbucket pipelines?

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines, openvpn

I'm trying to implement an CI tests on bitbucket pipelines .

To do so, I need to connect the pipelines to my OpenVPN server to be able to communicate with other client.

Here is my bitbucket-pipelines.yml :

```
pipelines:
default:
- step:
     script:

       - apk update 
       - apk upgrade 
       - apk --no-cache --no-progress add bash curl ip6tables iptables openvpn shadow tini sudo
       - adduser --system --no-create-home vpn
       - addgroup -S vpn
       - mkdir /dev/net
       - mknod /dev/net/tun c 10 200
       - chmod 666 /dev/net/tun
       - cp cloud.conf /etc/openvpn/
       - sudo openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/cloud.conf
```

The problem remain:

> Wed May 15 09:02:50 2019 WARNING: Since you are using --dev tun with a
>   point-to-point topology, the second argument to --ifconfig must be an
>   IP address.  You are using something (255.255.255.0) that looks more
>   like a netmask. (silence this warning with --ifconfig-nowarn) Wed May
>   15 09:02:50 2019 ROUTE_GATEWAY 169.254.1.1 Wed May 15 09:02:50 2019
>   ERROR: Cannot ioctl TUNSETIFF tun: Operation not permitted (errno=1)
>   Wed May 15 09:02:50 2019 Exiting due to fatal error